# How to create an EAN-13 barcode with a transparent background using Java?

Tags: java, barcode, ean-13, barbecue

I have attempted to create an EAN-13 barcode using multiple libraries such as barcodelib, barcode4j, zxing, and the barbecue library. I am generating the barcode on top of an image that has colors like green or blue. The libraries I am using create a barcode image with black bars and a white background. When this barcode image is placed on my colored background image, I end up with a green image and a barcode with a white background. I want the barcode to have the same background as the underlying image. Therefore, I want the barcode to be transparent.

Below is my code. I am using 'setOpaque' to set the background to transparent, but it still creates a barcode image with a white background.

```
public static BoolStr createBarbecueEAN13(String upcCode) throws OutputException, BarcodeException {
    // Generate EAN-13 Barcode
    Barcode barcode = BarcodeFactory.createEAN13(upcCode);

    // Set barcode properties
    barcode.setDrawingText(true);
    barcode.setOpaque(false);

    // Create a BufferedImage to draw the barcode
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(400, 200, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D g2d = image.createGraphics();

    // Set rendering hints to improve quality
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);

    int xPos = (image.getWidth() - barcode.getWidth()) / 2;
    int yPos = (image.getHeight() - barcode.getHeight()) / 2;
    barcode.draw(g2d, xPos, yPos);
    g2d.dispose();

    // Optionally, you can save the barcode image to a file
    saveBarcodeImage(barcode, tempFile.getPath());
    successPath = new BoolStr(tempFile.getPath(), true);
    return successPath;
}

  private static void saveBarcodeImage(Barcode barcode, String filePath) {
    try {
      BufferedImage image = BarcodeImageHandler.getImage(barcode);      
      BarcodeImageHandler.savePNG(barcode, new File(filePath));
      System.out.println("Barcode image saved to: " + filePath);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

Comment: The `BarcodeFactory` is probably creating an image with white pixels and black pixels.  To make the white pixels transparent, you have to go through the barcode image raster and change the white pixels to transparent pixels.  White is `new Color(255, 255, 255, 255)`.  Print some white pixels from your barcode image to be sure.  Transparent is `new Color(255, 255, 255, 0)`.